# Connect blocks/shapes in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I want to connect the arrow you see in the picture marked with a red square to the left blue square, I just want move the arrow a little bit more to the right but I can't, It goes through the blocks which I don't want, I would be glad if you can help me!

[image: Stupid visio]

Comment: I assume this is Visio 2013 ?

Comment: @Devid yes Visio 2013

Comment: Exactly how were those "blocks" created?  It looks like there's no connection points (unless you've hidden them?), and three of the existing middle arrows appear to be floating a pixel or two away from the left blue "block", so that makes me think they're not connected either (just "Lines" not actual "Connectors").

Comment: @techie007 The connection points are there. Shapes: drag-drop from quick shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the default Connection Points of the Shape but add your own ones to the shape and connect the lines through these connection points. (<kbd>Shift+Ctrl+1</kbd> then hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on shape)

Now connect the two shapes with the lines (connectors). They lines might overlap with the shape or other lines, but don't worry, just connect the shapes first. Now click on the line to select it, you will see dots on the line (connector). Hover your mouse over the dots (mouse will change shape) and you will see the popup message Move Midpoint. Just grub the line by the dot and move it so that it does not overlap with other shapes. This should do the trick.

Here is the result:

[image: Connectors and lines and shapes]